# Side by side barplots in r

Tags: r, bar-chart, difference

I have a data set that looks like this
[image: data]

I want to create side by side barplots that will show the differences between the two grades, I envisioned something like this

[image: barplot]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you can use `barplot` to iteratively lay over the values through a series of `par(new = TRUE)` and `ifelse` logic. You can add the text with similar logic using `text`:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2)) #side by side plot
# left plot
barplot(df$Grade_Semester1, names.arg = df$Person, horiz = TRUE, col = "grey", xlim = c(0, 10))

# right plot
barplot(ifelse(df$Difference < 0, df$Grade_Semester1, 0), 
        names.arg = df$Person, horiz = TRUE, col = "red", xlim = c(0, 10))
par(new = TRUE)
barplot(ifelse(df$Difference > 0, df$Grade_Semester2, 0), 
        names.arg = df$Person, horiz = TRUE, col = "green", xlim = c(0, 10))
par(new = TRUE)
xx <- barplot(pmin(df$Grade_Semester1, df$Grade_Semester2), 
        names.arg = df$Person, horiz = TRUE, col = "grey", xlim = c(0, 10))

text(pmin(df$Grade_Semester1, df$Grade_Semester2) + abs(pmin(df$Difference)/2),
     xx, ifelse(df$Difference == 0, "", ifelse(df$Difference > 0, paste0("+", df$Difference), df$Difference)))
```

[image]

Data

```
df <- data.frame(Person = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 Grade_Semester1 = c(9, 10, 8),
                 Grade_Semester2 = c(7, 10, 10),
                 Difference = c(-2, 0, 2))
```